# How can I see what Get restored?

Tags: save, persistence

Say I save variables `x`, `y`, `z` using `Save["stuff.dat", {x, y, z}]`. Is there any way, when using `Get["stuff.dat"]`, that I can see what are the names of the variables being restored?

Comment: You could use `$NewSymbol` to track if `Get[...]` defines any new symbols, but this won't tell you if an already existing symbol gets overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint):

```
a=2;
b=3;
c[x_]:=x^2

Save["tst.m", {a,b,c}];

TracePrint[
    Get["tst.m"],
    _Set | _SetDelayed
]
```

> a=2
>
> b=3
>
> c[x_]:=x^2

**Addendum**

If you just want to see the variables, you can add a custom [`TraceAction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraceAction):

```
TracePrint[
    Get["tst.m"],
    _Set | _SetDelayed,
    TraceAction->(Print[Extract[#, {1, 1}, HoldForm]]&)
]
```

> a
>
> b
>
> c[x_]

Comment: Will this work at the mx level though? I thought I remembered that preempting all my tricks

Comment: Thank you both for your help, but some of the variables I am restoring contain large amounts of data and these methods list every value along with the name. I don't need to know the values, just the variable names that have been restored. Is there a way to just list the variable names restored, but not their values?